# Getting blank output after mapping DataFrame with case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark job. I have data in a DF as follows:

```
df.show()
//+------+----------+
//|  name|      rank|
//+------+----------+
//|piyush|         1|
//+------+----------+
```

I want to map this DF as follows:

```
val ds = df.map(row=>{ConverterClass.convert(row)})
```

The method `ConverterClass.convert` is

```
def convert(row:Row):Data = {
    Data(
        row.getAs("name"),
        row.getAs("rank")
    )
}
```

and the case class `Data` is

```
case class Data (
    var name: String,
    var rank: String
)
```

When I am running this functionality, I am getting a blank output:

```
ds.show()
//++
//||
//++
//||
//++
```

I was using a Java class for Data earlier and using JavaSerializer, which was working fine. When I moved to using Scala case classes, I got this issue.

Comment: For convert to Case Class, method "as" can be used instead of ConverterClass: val ds = df.as[Data]

Comment: you should also reconsider using var's in case classes, prefer to use immutability and copy/lenses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! Your issue is in your `convert` method. A tiny part is missing in your usage of the [`getAs`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/api/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L372) method. Let's look at its signature:

```scala
def getAs[T](fieldName: String): T = getAs[T](fieldIndex(fieldName))
```

You're missing the addition of `[T]` in there, which is the type of the field you're trying to get your value from. In your case it will be `[String]` for both of your fields, as defined in your case class.

Here a fully reproducible example of your code (I only changed your convert function by adding `[String]` in there):

```scala
case class Data (
    var name: String,
    var rank: String
)

def my_convert(row:Row):Data = {
    Data(
        row.getAs[String]("name"),
        row.getAs[String]("rank"),
    )
}

val df = Seq(("piyush", "1")).toDF("name", "rank")

val ds = df.map(row=>{my_convert(row)})

scala> ds.show
+------+----+
|  name|rank|
+------+----+
|piyush|   1|
+------+----+
```